# Simple AJAX Request on Rails 4 without the use of Remote get back result on the Same Page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to bind a simple ajax request and get back the data I sent. A lot of tutorials keep on suggesting the use of "remote: true" which is not my case, I don't use a form at all.

**test\index.html.erb**

```
<script>

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/test/index",
        data: { username: "sample" }
    })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Sent: " + msg );
            });

</script>
```

**test_controller.erb**

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def index
    sample = params[:username]

    # I am totally lost here; there seems to be many suggestions; 
    # I just want to output the "sample" back to the "msg" for an alert();
    # Tried respond_to; just gives a page without the params...

  end

end
```

the main purpose for the entire thing is to check the username if exists; just simplified code.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't use a form

You'll need to *bind* your Ajax even to an *event* in your [DOM (Document Object Model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "a.button", function(e) {
   $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/test/index",
        data: { username: "sample" }
    }) .done(function( msg ) {
        data = JSON.parse(msg)
        alert( "Data Sent: " + data.message );
    });

});
```

[`remote: true`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) just binds a prebuild Ajax function to `$(form).on("submit"`... you may not see it, but it's there. If you're not using `remote: true`, or a `form`, you still need to bind your JS functionality to an event (as above).

*You do realize* you can use `remote: true` on other "request" elements, right?

```
<%= link_to "Test", tests_path, remote: true %>
<%= button_to "Test", tests_path, remote: true %>
```

In order to provide a response, your controller should use [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to):

```
#app/controllers/tests_controller.rb
class TestsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render json: {:"message" => "hello"}.to_json }
         format.html
      end
   end
end
```

This will return the `json` object to your ajax request, allowing you to append it to the DOM as you require (using the `jquery .done()` method).

---

To give some context,

[Javascript works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Use_in_web_pages) by taking a list of your HTML (called the "DOM") and "listens" to events which occur with each element.

This is how the DOM looks to JS:

[image]

Whenever you use javascript / jquery, you need to *bind* a function to an event. This is typically done with `.on`:

```
$("element").on("event", function(){
   // Do something when event is invoked
});
```

This allows you to tie functionality to specific events in the DOM.

Your main problem is you've not bound your `ajax` to any events - it's "naked"... JS simply don't know when to fire, and for what purpose.

---

## Notes

**Asset Pipeline**

You're currently including a `<script>` tag in your `index` view - this is **not** recommended.

You need to look up the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) -- all your javascript should be *unobtrusive*. This not only will allow you to reuse code as you need, but also keep your views clear for formatting.

---

**Update**

You make sure you have the following set up for your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :test, only: :index
```

Comment: All points taken in mind and implemented; I put everything in your code. Except I put it inside:

$( document ).ready(function() {
    # ajax code here
});

and I am getting a

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) on  http://localhost:3000/test/index 

I think data is not reaching controller somehow..

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :accesses

  devise_for :actors

  #devise_for :actors

    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]

    root 'home#index'

end

Comment: still getting unprocessable entity. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity); is it possible it has something to do with my turbolinks? or require_tree? i commented both  out..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the response? It normally says where the error shows. It might be to do with your datatype

Comment: im afraid thats all there is... it doesnt say what line of code just " http://localhost:3000/test/index Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)" I am using Chrome's "inspect element"

http://i65.tinypic.com/2nvnms.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93793/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-james).